# Defining maximum char[] array size allowable to C programs in linux

Tags: c, arrays, memory, memory-management, size

I have made code in C involving local char arrays, but I read that if the size of the arrays are too high then a segmentation fault may occur.

In my code, I included the following line:

```
#include <stdint.h>
```

And I also added in the output section:

printf("%d",SIZE_MAX);

Upon execution, I see a -1 which suggests to me Unlimited.

I then proceed into a console and checked my limits:

```
bash-3.1# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 8189
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 4096
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 4096
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 8189
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

And I see many "unlimited"'s.

Am I looking in the right place to define the maximum allowable size for a char[] array? If so, Which value do I need to modify?

Comment: So long as it is not on the stack. The array has to be indexable so I think `SIZE_MAX` is the limit.

Comment: In the limits, the line you care about is `stack size` which indicates that the maximum stack size is 4096 kilobytes, i.e. 4 megabytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to modify the `stack` size. `-s` is the option to set stack size using `ulimit`.

On your system currently it is 4 megabytes.

```
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 4096
```

Ex:

```
ulimit -s unlimited 
//sets stack size to ulimited
```

Answer (score 0):

Printf is showing you a `-1` since the format of `%d` is a signed integer which is smaller than unsigned (usually by 1 bit).  Function local character arrays go on the stack so that's the value you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Linux has a virtual memory manager that will allocate blocks as needed, swap blocks out to disk, and otherwise try to make the system look like there's no pre-set limit to how much memory you can allocate to a specific task. But that's like an American Express card with "no pre-set spending limit". If you try to charge a Ferrari, they're going to call you and ask "WTF?". In reality, all memory is finite, and so memory tricks will fail at some point. Unfortunately, there is no practical way to know what that point is in advance. It depends upon what else is running on the system, the size and speed of your disk, OS settings, and other things.

As a practical matter, allocating an array close to the amount of physical RAM in the machine is likely to cause problems (slowdowns, if nothing else). So that might be a reasonable limit to consider. Memory-mapped files might be another thing to consider, but reality intrudes on their performance as well at some point.

Comment: The system won’t blink when you allocate an array close the amount of physical memory. It is when you use it that effects are noticed.